# how to pass validation test in AutoML Vision

Tags: google-cloud-automl, automl

how to pass validation on AutoML?
i already upload 10 image with "Car" label.
still cant pass validation.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i was delete the dataset and reupload all the image at once and then drawing boundingbox again, i dont know waht it just works